# vue3: How to disable a component-button conditionally?

Tags: vuejs3

If there are less than 3 chars in the text field, I want to disable Create button, i.e TodoButton, how? I don't want to hide it, I want to disable it.

Pic:
[image]

Non working code

```js
<script setup>
import { ref, reactive } from 'vue';
import TodoButton from "./_TodoButton.vue"

const todoState = reactive({
  todo: "",
  invalid: false,
  errorMsg: ""
})

const emit = defineEmits(["create-todo"])
const createTodo = () => {
    
    if(todoState.todo !== ""){
        todoState.invalid = false;
        emit("create-todo", todoState.todo)
        todoState.todo = ""
        return
    }
    todoState.invalid = true
    todoState.errorMsg = "Todo value can not be empty"
}
</script>

<template>
    <div class="input-wrap" :class="{ 'input-err' : todoState.invalid}">
        <input type="text" v-model="todoState.todo"/>
        <TodoButton @click="createTodo()" :disabled="todoState.todo.length < 3">Create</TodoButton>
    </div>
    <p>{{ todoState.todo }}</p>
    <p v-show="todoState.invalid" class="err-msg">{{ todoState.errorMsg }}</p>
</template>
```

TodoButton -- This must remain disabled if there are less than 3 chars in text field

```js
<script setup>

</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <button>
            <slot></slot>
        </button>   
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able pass @disabled from parent to child TodoButton. Ended up creating a props isDisabled in child button component i.e TodoButton

```js
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  isDisabled : {
            type: Boolean,
            required: false,
            default: true
        }
})
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <button :disabled="isDisabled">
            <slot></slot>
        </button>   
    </div>
</template>
```

and then passing isDisabled custom prop to child , like below

```js
<template>
    <div class="input-wrap" :class="{ 'input-err' : todoState.invalid}">
        <input type="text" v-model="todoState.todo"/>
        <TodoButton @click="createTodo()" :isDisabled="todoState.todo.length < 3">Create</TodoButton>
    </div>
    <p>{{ todoState.todo }}</p>
    <p v-show="todoState.invalid" class="err-msg">{{ todoState.errorMsg }}</p>
</template>
```

Comment: You could declare `disabled` as a prop on your component and use that, so that it's the same as the native attribute.

Comment: you have use `useAttrs`